# Implementing Google Assistant voice command support

Tags: android

I am working on implementing voice commands for Android media App. I am having trouble getting Google Assistant to recognize that I am asking to play a title on my application: “Play [x] on MyApp”. I understand that it takes a few days after being published for this command to work, but I should still be able to say “Play [x]” while the media session is already running and it should use onPrepareFromSearch and onPlayFromSearch methods to search for and play content.

When I say “Play [x] on MyApp” I get the response “I looked for [x] on MyApp on Google Play Music but it either isn’t available or it can’t be played right now”. When I say “Play [x]” while my media service is running it will usually redirect me to Google Play Music.

Things I have tried:

- Added an  for MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH to an activity in
  my application as to mark my application available to search for
  media
- Implemented onPrepareFromSearch and onPlayFromSearch in my
  MediaSessionCompat.Callback
- Added ACTION_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH and ACTION_PREPARE_FROM_SEARCH as
  supported actions.
- Set the media session flags FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS and
  FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS

Is there a step I am missing in order to get this to work?

Comment: Did you succeed? To me, it works for pause/restart when I launched from my app. But saying to Assistant play live from MyApp, it starts Youtube.

Comment: @Stephane, it's the same